# Zend Db Illegal mix of collations and sytnax error using COLLATE

Tags: php, mysql, zend-db

I was trying to join two columns in tables that used different collation using Zend Db and I got this error:

```
Illegal mix of collations (utf8_general_ci,IMPLICIT) and (utf8_unicode_ci,IMPLICIT) for operation '=')
```

After googling and finding a few questions on Stackoverflow I added `COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci` onto my join like so:

```
        $select = $this->getSql()->select();
        $select->columns(['*', new Expression('count(*) as count')]);
        $select->join(
            ['tbl2' => 'table2'],
            'table1.name COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci = tbl2.name',
            ['person_id' => 'id'],
            $select::JOIN_LEFT
        );
```

But now I get a different error:

```
...
could not be executed (42000 - 1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax;
check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for 
the right syntax to use near '`COLLATE` `utf8_unicode_ci`
```

This is because Zend automatically backquotes the keyword `COLLATE` for me but I want to use a reserved word in the `join` condition.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ideally you should change your collation so that both match, then you can join those tables using that condition without the `COLLATE` keyword. I'm not sure but I would guess using `COLLATE` in a join will probably impact performance.

If you cannot change the schema then alternatively, you could use `Predicate\Expression` instead on a string join which seems to bypass the auto quoting:

```
        $select = $this->getSql()->select();
        $select->columns(['*', new Expression('count(*) as count')]);
        $select->join(
            ['tbl2' => 'table2'],
            new \Zend\Db\Sql\Predicate\Expression('table1.name COLLATE utf8_unicode_ci = table2.name'),
            ['person_id' => 'id'],
            $select::JOIN_LEFT
        );
```

Or I guess you can bypass using Zend and handwrite the SQL statement yourself..